# A Module For Installing Modules in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am wondering if there is a module that gives the ability to install modules via an interface instead of copy a module files and create database tables manually and add it to config/main.php .

Is there any ? I mean something like what is in Joomla or Drupal?

Comment: It may Possible on yii. I think Currently there is no interface to do that.  You can write interface for this specific purpose. Good objective 1+

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I don't think there is something like this on Yii.
What we did for our projects, is this.
We created our module, that will automatically create / copy the files 
and the same time, add the configuration files.